# FullCalendar events colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

> I have a calendar, and outside of this I have a box where I put the event values (client, barber, service and I choose a color). After loading the values, an element is generated that I can select and drag to the calendar. *The following happens to me:*

When I create an event and drag it to the calendar, it is placed with the color that I configured. If I click the save button, it loads correctly into the database. A `json` is saved with the event information, for example:

```
{"id":2,"title":"Maria Marco","barbero":"Diego","servicio":"Corte","start":"2020-03-21T10:30:00","end":"2020-03-21T11:00:00","color":"rgb(0, 86, 179)"}
```

Suppose I don't have any items in the database, and I create 3 events and drag them to the calendar. If I click the save button, these 3 will be saved correctly as indicated above.

Now if I do a new event load, these new elements will load correctly, but in the previous elements the `color` property now disappears.

I appreciate if any find the error in this spaghetti of `js`

```
$(function() {         
        var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        // initialize the external events
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------

        new FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable(containerEl, {
            itemSelector: '.external-event',
            eventData: function(eventEl) {

                var barbero = $("#barbero").children(".opcion-barbero:selected").html()
                var servicio = $("#servicio").val()
                return {
                    title: eventEl.innerText,
                    extendedProps: { "barbero": barbero, "servicio": servicio, "color": eventEl.style.backgroundColor },
                    backgroundColor: eventEl.style.backgroundColor,
                    borderColor: eventEl.style.backgroundColor
                };
            }
        });

        view = 'timeGridDay';
        header = {
            left: 'prev,next timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth',
            center: '',
            right: ''
        };

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            timeZone: 'local',
            plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
            eventSources: [
                // your event source
                {
                    url: 'ajax/turnos2.ajax.php'
                }
            ],

            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function(info) {

                info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);

            }
        });

        calendar.render();
        /* ADDING EVENTS */
        var currColor = '#3c8dbc' //Red by default
            //Color chooser button
        var colorChooser = $('#color-chooser-btn')
        $('#color-chooser > li > a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
                //Save color
            currColor = $(this).css('color')
                //Add color effect to button
            $('#add-new-event').css({
                'background-color': currColor,
                'border-color': currColor
            })
        })

        $('#add-new-event').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
                //Get value and make sure it is not null
            var val = $('#new-event').val()
            if (val.length == 0) {
                return
            }


            //Create events
            var event = $('<div />')
            event.css({
                'font-weight': 300,
                'background-color': currColor,
                'border-color': currColor,
                'color': '#fff'
            }).addClass('external-event')
            event.html(val)


            $('#external-events').prepend(event)

            //Add draggable funtionality
            ini_events(event)

            //Remove event from text input
            $('#new-event').val('')
        })


        /*==============================================
        Apply changes to the events
        ==============================================*/

        $(document).on("click", "span.guardarCalendario", function() {

            var arrayEventos = new Array();
            var eventos = calendar.getEvents();

            // Contador para ID
            var num = 1;
            eventos.forEach(e => {

                // Nombre del turno
                title = (e._def["title"]);
                barbero2 = (e._def.extendedProps["barbero"]);
                servicio = (e._def.extendedProps["servicio"]);
                color = (e._def.extendedProps["color"]);
                id = num;
                num = num + 1;

                var evento = new Object();
                evento["id"] = id;
                evento["title"] = title;
                evento["barbero"] = barbero2;
                evento["servicio"] = servicio;
                evento["start"] = start;
                evento["end"] = end;
                evento["color"] = (e._def.extendedProps["color"]);

                arrayEventos.push(evento);

            })

            $("#turnos").val(JSON.stringify(arrayEventos))

            var data = { 'data': JSON.stringify(arrayEventos) }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: data,
                success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                    alert("response was " + data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, errorMessage) {
                    $("#debug").append("RESPONSE: " + xhr.responseText + ", error: " + errorMessage);
                }
            });
        })
```

> turnos.ajax.php

```
<?php

require_once "../modelos/turnos.modelo.php";
require_once "../controladores/turnos.controlador.php";

class AjaxTurnos{

    public $data;
    public function ajaxActualizarTurnos(){
        $datos = ($this->data);
        foreach(json_decode($datos) as $value){
              $respuesta = ModeloTurnos::mdlActualizarTurnos(json_encode($value).PHP_EOL);
        }
        return $respuesta;
    }

}

    /*==============================
    ACTUALIZAR TURNOS
    ==============================*/
    if(isset($_POST["data"])){

        ModeloTurnos::mdlTruncarTurnos();
        $turnos = new AjaxTurnos();
        $turnos -> data = $_POST["data"];
        $turnos -> ajaxActualizarTurnos();
    }
```

> turnos2.ajax.php

```
<?php

require_once "../modelos/turnos.modelo.php";
require_once "../controladores/turnos.controlador.php";



    $data = ControladorTurnos::ctrMostrarTurnos();
    $data2 = [];
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $data2[] = json_decode($value["datos"]);
    }
    //returns data as JSON format
    echo (json_encode($data2));
```

Comment: "if I do a new event load"...to be clear, by this do you mean refreshing all the events from the database? Or something else?

Comment: I can create events and drag them onto the calendar. Then, I press the "save" button and ALL the events that are in the calendar are saved in the database. Newly dragged events save well, but the "color" property of those already was in the calendar will be removed. I hope to make myself understood, my English is not very good

Comment: "new event load" would be create, drag, drop and save

Comment: This is where you do the saving, am I right: `$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/turnos.ajax.php',...` ? If so then, the only thing which happens after the saving is `alert("response was " + data);`. That cannot affect anything inside fullCalendar. It's hard to understand what the cause could be.

Comment: That function brings all the events from my database. But it brings them well. The problem is when I do a new load, this overwrites the events that already existed and removes the "color" property. Only new events (from the last load) have the property "color" correctly.

Comment: the save function is  `` $(document).on("click", "span.guardarCalendario", function() { ``

Comment: "That function brings all the events from my database"...it can't do. It looks like that's where you **send** events. I am talking about turnos.ajax.php, not turnos2.ajax.php

Comment: I think you should show the code of both of the PHP files, though. it would help.

Comment: youre right, this is the load function, im sorry. I will put those codes. Sorry and thanks,

Comment: can you post turnos2 as well please

Comment: @ADyson yes, done

Comment: Ok Thanks. Lastly, sorry, can you post your HTML as well. I'm trying to make a demo so I can see the problem occurring, but it's hard without the HTML showing how the external events are made, and the buttons and so on. Thanks.

Comment: gimme 5 minuts and i up js + html to codepen, i remove some functions in the js for make the question

Comment: https://codepen.io/agustinguerr4/pen/YzXjXdL

Comment: you must install ``fullCalendar`` and use dummydata for the selects. If i can do some for help you, please just say it

Comment: ok give me a little time, I  will work on it

Comment: I had quite a good go at this and I'm really not able to see the problem, to be honest. Did I miss something? https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/GRJBJdB